# Android: transparent background for custom drawable

Tags: android, drawable

I drew up a custom drawable icon in MS paint, but when I load the image it has a white background instead of transparent, how do I fix this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

MS Paint probably saved this without a transparent background. Id recommend using something like GIMP or Paint.NET to create this icon. They are both available free.

You probably need to save it as either a .gif file or a .png file too, as these are compatible with transparency (and Android).

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use better editor for your purposes, which could make the background of your image transparent. MS Paint has no such possibilities.